# Use code for Data Explorer functionality rather than GUI

Tags: matlab

In Matlab's Database toolbox, I used the Data Explorer to set up a data source corresponding to my accdb file.  Is there a way to do perform Data Explorer functions using code rather than the GUI?

This has been posted on:

- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31327713/use-code-for-data-explorer-functionality-rather-than-gui)
- [comp.soft-sys.matlab](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.matlab/_IkwBlRU-BA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following response from TMW solved my problem:

'...the File DSN example on the database function page?  Example is titled: “Connect to Microsoft Access Using a File DSN”.  This allows you to build a path that you can use in the database function as the last input argument.  In this case, no data source setup is required.  Hence, everything can be done by writing code on the command line or a MATLAB script.'

Here is some sample code that uses the above solution to connect to the *.accdb file, pull in data, and use the data:

```
wbe3accdb_path='C:\cygwin64\home\My.User.Name\Projects\SomeProject\WBEs\wbe3\wbe3.accdb';
wbe3accdb_url= [ 'jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DSN='';DBQ=' wbe3accdb_path ];
conn = database('','','','sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver',wbe3accdb_url); 

curs=exec(conn,'SELECT * FROM SomeTableInAccdbDatabase')
curs=fetch(curs)
columnnames(curs)
close(conn)
scatter( ...
  curs.Data.SomeNumericalFieldName, ...
  curs.Data.AnotherNumericalFieldName, ...
  's' ...
)
set(gca,'xscale','log','yscale','log')

corr( ...
  curs.Data.SomeNumericalFieldName, ...
  curs.Data.AnotherNumericalFieldName, ...
  'rows', ...
  'pairwise' ...
)
```